# Access an Android purely via VNC enabling Tablet resolutions

Tags: screen, vnc

I can currently access my Android via VNC on my iPad.  Can I set the screen resolution of the Android to be the same as the native iPad resolution, giving me a pseudo Android tablet?

Even if there is an answer which corrupts the screen on the phone itself is fine, seeing it will be accessed via the tablet.

Comment: Which VNC server/client apps are you using on both your Android and iOS devices?  It most likely depends on the capabilities of those particular apps.

Comment: droid VNC server and iTeleport

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot change the resolution of Android in VNC in a standard way. However, some Android phones have additional functions to support HDMI (which results in running Android at a higher resolution). If you can somehow tap into that functionality in conjunction with VNC, then you might be able to get a 480p, 720p, and 1080p option. But this is something that would be highly customized to a single phone as all of the different HDMI implementations seem to vary tremendously. One other option that would be yet another one-off possibility (with some custom work) would be if your phone supports WebTop functionality. If so, perhaps you could tap into this.

However, there is no third-party app that does what you're wanting. To do this, you'll have to develop or find somebody to develop this highly-customized solution.

As other have suggested, you're probably not going to get much better than changing the LCD Density, which clearly isn't what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite the answer to your question, but you could run an android emulator (on a desktop computer) created with your desired resolution, and run the VNC server on that.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing LCD density and see if that works for you http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/change-android-screen-resolution-with-lcd-density/

Comment: That's basically one of the first Google search results, and it doesn't change the resolution of the screen.